# Find all usages of C# class recursively

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I've made some changes to the class and it is located in some shared project, so it can be used in many websites. How can I determine which projects will be affected?

The cases when this is useful: I want to update only changed production servers or I want to understand, how harmful is my change.

Current solution (using resharper or only visual studio): find usages of class, then find usages of all usages, then find usages of usages of usages and so on. Is there any way to make it easier?

Comment: Yes, using abstractions and encapsulating + unit/integration tests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For methods you're changing you can put your cursor on the methodname and press ctrl+shift+alt+A and pick 'Incoming calls', this way you can see the whole hierarchy where this method is used. If you follow through those hierarchies you can find in which projects and classes this method in your shared project is used.

Comment: Thank you, it's still not fully automatic, but it's very easier now!